# g++ linking against static library

Tags: c++

my `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

int foo(int arg);

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = foo(22);
    cout << x;
    return 0;
}
```

compile command line (Ubuntu 13.10):

```
g++-4.8 -L. -lfoo main.cpp -o main_app
```

`libfoo.a` contains `int foo(int)`
but I always get the same compiler error:

```
/tmp/cciAyTSP.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `foo(int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: `foo` is not **defined** inside your code, or in better terms it's not defined or `extern` inside your translation unit.

Comment: How do you build libfoo.a? Could you give us a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: @user2485710 Functions do not need to be declared `extern`

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I didn't said that ... for example this code lacks of any header or inclusions that could have helped to solve the problem. `extern` is implicit, I know that .

Comment: @user2485710: Header inclusion is not necessary.

Comment: @Beta if you want to avoid the definition of a function inside a translation unit, yes it is ...

Comment: @user2485710: If you mean avoid having the definition of `foo` in `main.cpp`, you're wrong. What do you think the `#include` directive does?

Comment: @Beta like all other libraries, it `extern` the symbol

Comment: @user2485710: I think it is now safe to say that neither of us knows what you're talking about.

Comment: @Beta nevermind, the op can either define the function used inside this piece of code, right in the source file, or remove the definition and include an header to an external library that will be solved when linking. Problem is that the combination of the source code and the command line doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I don't have any .h files but I don't need them as long as I know function signatures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it's impossible to be sure without a reproducible case, but a common error is that if the function `foo` is written in C then you need to put

```
extern "C" { int foo(int); }
```

in the `.h` file for the C++ program to let it know that the function was not written in C++.

To write a cross-language header file that will be good for both C and C++ the common approach is

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

... C declarations ...

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: also, move -lfoo to the end of the command.

Comment: @Xephon no, it doesn't help

Comment: @iamnp Not moving the linkage statement may cause other issues. Not trying to answer the question but introducing a better practice per se.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to 6502's answer and Xephon's suggestion, also be aware that the order of the options matter. Instead of:

```
g++-4.8 -L. -lfoo main.cpp -o main_app
```

You should write:

```
g++-4.8 main.cpp -o main_app -L. -lfoo
```

That's because `ld` is a single pass linker. It won't revisit library `libfoo` to use a symbol from it for `main_app.o`.